# magento2 : custom layout file issue

Tags: magento2

my system log says:

```
[2016-07-07 06:57:49] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_3bc116a8dbf5ce43f9f3e452fa24f453b and handles default, tglssearch_result_index: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []

[2016-07-07 06:57:49] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_3a7ccd8094436548b564a588f6303121c and handles 2columns-left: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
```

My custom layout file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Navigation" before="-" name="catalogsearch.leftnav" template="Vendor_Module::search/filter.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

Could someone please help on this .

Answer (score 2):

I think the block's template attribute must be named

```
template="Vendor_Module::search/filter.phtml"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is might be a problem:

```
//case #1
magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Update/Validator:118

$this->_domConfigFactory->createDom(['xml' => $value, 'schemaFile' => $this->_xsdSchemas[$schema]]);

//case #2
magento/framework/Config/Dom.php:311
\Magento\Framework\Config\Dom::validateDomDocument()

$result = $dom->schemaValidate($schema);
```

So, merged XML doesn't match to required schema file.
I got the same problem. Seem, merged native files might have some issues as well.